# File added to assets folder after ng serve are not served by Angular

Tags: angular, file-upload, http-status-code-404, assets

I have a file upload control in my Angular project which uploads files to `assets/images` folder. On the success of file upload, I would like to preview the uploaded file with URL `http://localhost:4001/assets/images/filename.jpg`. But the URL gives 404 Not Found error even the file exists in `assets/images` folder.

It seems Angular's assets folder is meant to serve only static files which can be copied on the build. What are all the possibilities to get the dynamic files to display immediately after upload?

I tried to upload files outside the assets folder, but it is not able to serve the file with a relative path.

I would expect the files to be served from Angular App's URL instead of using any CDN services.

Any help/suggestion to use dynamic assets will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you uploading image in assets folder of  your server or in your angular application ? @Gopinath

Comment: I am uploading image to assets folder of anuglar application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a backend service to handle file uploads, and avoid uploading files to Assets directory.

Essentially you should be posting the image to backend over an API call so the backend (whatever the programming language is) can do the saving part for you (and probably return the image path as the result of same API call).

Comment: Yes. That's how I managed to fix it. But need to understand why Angular is not able to serve the files placed inside its hosting path like other web applications do.

Comment: @Gopinath if you're talking about the environment at "ng serve", it simply compiles your code and create a virtual server using webpack-dev-server ( https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#webpack-dev-server ), so once you do a modification, it simply compiles again & push the code to the virtual server.

Your solution should work on prod deployments, but will be flushed upon new deployments (unless you carefully replace all the new files only)